# If-then condition formulation to avoid variable multiplication

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, constraint, indicator-constraints, reformulation-linearization

I'm trying to formulate the following logic:
If $y_i =1$, then $c_i \leq x_i$
If $y_i =0$, then $c_i \leq 0$
Where $y_i$, $c_i$, and $x_i$ are decision variables.

The easy way would be to write:
$$c_i \leq x_i y_i$$
But that is a quadratic formulation. I was wondering if there is a way to write the constraint as a linear one.

Consider that $c_i$, $x_i$ $\geq 0$ and $y_i \in \{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like: $$\begin{align} & c_i \le x_i + M(1-y_i)\\ & c_i \le My_i \end{align}$$ $M$ can be interpreted as an upperbound on $c_i$. If you don't like the big-$M$'s, consider using indicator constraints.

See the comments below for some improvements on this!

Comment: Erwin knows this, but a best practice is to use $M_i$ (a possibly different value for each $c_i$).

Comment: And may be even a different $M_i$ for the two constraints (if we know something about the difference between $c_i$ and $x_i$).

Comment: Since $x_i\ge 0$, the first constraint can be simplified to $c_i \le x_i$.

Comment: Great, I missed that.

Comment: Indeed, Paul's improvement arises from interpreting the first $M$ as a (small) upper bound on $c_i-x_i$ **when $y_i=0$**.  Because $c_i=0$ in that case, we have $c_i-x_i = -x_i \le 0$, so take $M=0$.